# Split string in row into separate string (into a column)

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, split

SQL Query:
Input:

```
| Company |  
| --------| 
|  APPLE  |    
| GOOGLE  |
```

Needed Output:

```
|One | Two |   
|----------| 
| A  |  G  |
| P  |  O  |
| P  |  O  |
| L  |  G  |
| E  |  L  |
|    |  E  |
```

Tried using string_split function.
New to SQL. Can't get the desired output. Please help :)

Comment: Which are you using, MySQL or Oracle? Don't add irrelevant tags.

Comment: Microsoft SQL. I am also coding on Oracle SQL Dev. Any query result would be fine with me :)

Comment: `string_split()` requires a delimiter character. It doesn't look like there's a similar function that splits each character.

Comment: 'Any query result would be fine with me' -are you looking for a generic solution?

Comment: What result do you want if there are two rows? A hundred? A million?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: This is a very strange requirement. What reason would you need to mangle your data like this? To be honest, a query is probably the wrong tool for this kind of thing.

Comment: This looks more like some presentation requirment rather than a query resultset? How are you intending to consume this resultset? How would it handle values for many rows of greatly varying length? You also forgot to include what you tried and where it was not working.

Comment: Apply letter numbers, pivot. [Oracle dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/t796bWNG).

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure what you're looking to achieve here, but to produce the result set you asked for:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (Company NVARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @TABLE (Company) VALUES
('Apple'),('Google'),('Microsoft'),('Meta');

;WITH Numbers AS (
SELECT 1 AS Number, (SELECT MAX(LEN(Company)) FROM @TABLE) AS MaxNumber
UNION ALL
SELECT Number+1, MaxNumber
  FROM Numbers
 WHERE Number < MaxNumber
)

SELECT MAX([1]) AS one, MAX([2]) AS two, MAX([3]) AS three, MAX([4]) AS four
  FROM (
        SELECT *, SUBSTRING(Company,Number,1) AS c
          FROM (SELECT Company, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Rn FROM @TABLE) a
          CROSS APPLY Numbers
       ) a
    PIVOT (
           MAX(c) FOR Rn IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
          ) p
 GROUP BY Number
```

This is pretty gnarly, and would need to be manually adjusted to produce more results (unless you go down the dynamic SQL pivot road).

Essentially what we're doing here is building a CTE to hold the numbers from 1 to the length of the longest string and then applying it to the data. Using that number we can produce a substring of 1 from that position. Then to put them into columns (from rows) we pivot on the `ROW_NUMBER` (in no particular order) and produce the MAX string value for each rows position. Finally, to compress the result down into a single set of rows we take the MAX value for each position grouped by that row number.